# Why page is not loaded in Java Spring boot Angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem with load a simple page where will be display all messages. I using algular for front-end and spring boot app in back-end. When i try to load page (localhost:8080/messages), page is blank and give me to download JSON with messages. Any idea? Ps. in ViewAllMessages.html i write constant text to check when page is running.

MessageController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/message")
public class MessageController {

private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageController.class);

@Autowired
private MessageService messageService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = GET)
public List<MessageDTO> findAll() {
    LOG.info("Received request to all messages.");
    return messageService.findAll();
}
}
```

main.js

```
var chatApp = angular.module('chat', ['ngRoute']);

 chatApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/messages',
        {
         controller: 'AllMessagesController',
         templateURL: '/partials/ViewAllMessages.html'
        })
    .otherwise( {redirectTo: '/'});
 });

 chatApp.service('messageService', function(){
var message = {};

var addMessage = function (v) {
   message = v;
};
var getMessage = function(){
   return message;
};

 return {
   addMessage: addMessage,
   getMessage: getMessage
 };

 });

chatApp.controller('AllMessagesController', function($scope, $window, $http){
 $scope.transfer = {};
 $scope.error = false;
 $http
   .get('/api/message/all')
   .then(function(response) {
       $scope.messages = response.data;
       log.console(response.data);
   });
});
```

index.html

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/office.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">  </style>
<body>

<script src="js/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/angular-resource.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

ViewAllMessages.html

```
 <div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h2>Wiadomosci</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>>

<div class="section">
    <h3>{{headingTitle}}</h3>
    <div>
        <ul type="square">
            <li>Luke</li>
            <li>Darth</li>
            <li>Anakin</li>
            <li>Leia</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="message in messages">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="panel-default"> {{message.id}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="panel-default"> {{message.message}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>>
</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: first of all i see in the index.html the order of the script import, so try to put firs angular.min.js.

Comment: i did that but doesnt work ;/

Answer (score 0):

page didn't show because you didn't import **$routeParams** dependency into your controller in **index.js**. After setting it, page shows up.